# Post to type posts in subdirectory.

Tags: custom-post-types, add-submenu-page

I would like to do the following: I have a blog with my domain ***www.examplesite.com*** and got some posts on it. But I would like to move some of the posts into a subdirectory ***www.examplesite.com/extras***. 
I know it's possible to create a post type for this, but the problem is I don't know exactly how to transform the subdomain into ***www.extras.examplesite.com*** in ***www.examplesite.com/extras*** and move only extra posts categorized into this subdirectory using only codes within functions.php. 
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is dependent upon your hosting environment (IIS, nginx, Apache, etc.).  In a nutshell, you are looking to perform a redirect while preserving the original query.  Consider https://serverfault.com/a/548595 for an example of one such redirect being performed within nginx.